# Puzzle in inference about integral formulation.

Tags: integration

I am reading a paper about communication. But I cannt infer this formulation
$$
C(p) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} B\log_2(1+\frac{p x}{BN})f(x) dx\\
= \frac{B}{\ln 2}\frac{p}{BN} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-F(x)}{1+\frac{px}{BN}} dx
$$

To simplify, I ignore some meaningless symbol in origin paper. In this formulation, $F(x) = \int f(x) dx = 1 - e^{-x/m}$ , $m, B, N$ are constant.

I tried to use Integration by parts, but first part is unbounded, it does not work. So I have to ask your help T^T. Anyway, thx!

Comment: Please show explicitly the integration by parts (using the explicit formula for $f$), and mentioning which part is unbounded. (There is a closing pending going on in parallel, doing this would prevent the question from closing, but in an optimistic perspective doing so will make you find the answer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys to see it, I had solved it by other people's help! Now let me show it:
\begin{align*}
C(p) &= \int_{0}^{+\infty} B\log_2(1+\frac{p x}{BN})f(x) dx\\
&= \frac{B}{\ln2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\ln(1+\frac{px}{BN})d(-(1-F(x)))\\
&= \frac{B}{\ln2}\left[ -(1-F(x))\ln(1+\frac{px}{BN})\bigg|_{0}^{+\infty}+ \frac{p}{BN} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-F(x)}{1+\frac{px}{BN}} dx \right]\\
&= \frac{B}{\ln2}\left(\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{px}{BN})}{e^{\frac{x}{m}}}-0\right) +G(x)\\
&= \frac{B}{\ln2}\left(\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{1+\frac{p}{BN}}{(1+\frac{px}{BN})(\frac{1}{m}e^{\frac{x}{m}})}\right) +G(x)\\
&= G(x)\\
&= \frac{B}{\ln 2}\frac{p}{BN} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-F(x)}{1+\frac{px}{BN}} dx
\end{align*}